# WebStorm settings for local modules import/require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, webstorm

Is it possible to configure where WebStorm is looking for modules without adding the project itself as a library in the settings?

I have added the following part to webpack and compiling works fine, but I also need code completion

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve('./asset/js')
    ]
},
```

Now I can change something like this:

```
import { ViewContainer } from './../../application';
```

to:

```
import { ViewContainer } from 'application';
```

But with this I have no code completion and adding `/asset/js` to the Library seems not to work. It also disables checking for errors on this directory.

WebStorm gives me the warning that no module 'application' is found in `package.json`

package.json only accept npm modules or git repositories

Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the directory and go to 'Mark Directory as' and select 'Resource Root'